# Chemical Reaction ammonium hydroxide + aluminum chloride (3NH4OH + AlCl3 -> 3NH4Cl + Al(OH)3)

Tags: experimental-chemistry

What is the color of the precipitate of Al(OH)3?

Comment: Can you clarify what your issue is? If it is as stated, please change the title of your question as it doesn't have anything to do with the actual question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_hydroxide

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure that it's white.  Maalox is essentially an aluminum hydroxide solution and it's white.  There is nothing structurally or electronically to suggest that it would be any other color.